# Crystal Reports 2008 Dynamic Parameter with option to select None

Tags: parameters, nullable, crystal-reports-2008

I've made a parameter called **AR Status** that I'm using to filter report output in the Select Expert. The formula for the filter is:

```
{CMS_Invoice.AR_STATUS} <> {?AR Status}
```

As shown below there are four choices in this dynamic value parameter. However I would like these choices to be optional. As it is now you must choose one or all of the values. I would like the ability to choose no values basically nullifying the parameter filter at report run time if desired. If I don't choose at least one value the parameter screen will not close.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can skip the prompt window by not choosing atleast one value.. on thing you can do is to add `None` to the prompt and if you don't want to select any option then select `None` and proceed.

Comment: How can I add None? The dynamic parameter currently pulls directly from the available choices on the table. Can I add an additional choice?

Comment: Ohh its a dynamic parameter then if possible you can add a default value as none in table itself

Comment: I can't alter the underlying SQL Table is there a way to alter it within Crystal Reports?

Comment: If we are using dynamic parameters to the extent I know there is no other way

Comment: I could change it to a static parameter since there are only 4 choices, but how do I add a choice for None?

Comment: when you create a parameter you can enter values one by one below the parameter name.. there add first value as `None` also you can mention `None` as default value using one of the option to the last of the parameter window...